# When connecting to LUIS, what does the "forceset" parameter do

Tags: azure-language-understanding

In my LUIS app I have an intent called GetWeather requiring a Location to be set. [image: GetWeather intent with Location as required parameter]

When connecting to the app using the query

> What is the weather in london

it correctly returns

```
{
  "query": "what is the weather in london",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "GetWeather",
    "score": 0.999875546,
    "actions": [
      {
        "triggered": true,
        "name": "GetWeather",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "Location",
            "type": "Location",
            "required": true,
            "value": [
              {
                "entity": "london",
                "type": "Location",
                "resolution": {}
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "london",
      "type": "Location",
      "startIndex": 23,
      "endIndex": 28,
      "score": 0.832388461,
      "resolution": {}
    }
  ],
  "dialog": {
    "contextId": "e1df6c2d-e691-4fc6-89f2-3ee2ef519724",
    "status": "Finished"
  }
}
```

If I instead use the query

> What is the weather

It returns the following expected result.

```
{
  "query": "what is the weather",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "GetWeather",
    "score": 1.0,
    "actions": [
      {
        "triggered": false,
        "name": "GetWeather",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "Location",
            "type": "Location",
            "required": true,
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "entities": [],
  "dialog": {
    "prompt": "Where",
    "parameterName": "Location",
    "parameterType": "Location",
    "contextId": "3b0725f4-7d6f-43fd-ab6e-02fc11c3eed1",
    "status": "Question"
  }
}
```

I thought that using the contextID together with the forceSet parameter in my next call would set the parameter Location to whatever I send as the query. The conection string I use is this:

```
https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v2.0/apps/{APP_ID}?subscription-key={SUBSCRIPTION_KEY}&q=london&contextid=3b0725f4-7d6f-43fd-ab6e-02fc11c3eed1&forceset=Location
```

Instead I get the following response back:

```
{
  "query": "london",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "GetWeather",
    "score": 1.0,
    "actions": [
      {
        "triggered": false,
        "name": "GetWeather",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "Location",
            "type": "Location",
            "required": true,
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "entities": [],
  "dialog": {
    "prompt": "Where",
    "parameterName": "Location",
    "parameterType": "Location",
    "contextId": "3b0725f4-7d6f-43fd-ab6e-02fc11c3eed1",
    "status": "Question"
  }
}
```

I had expected to get something like my first response back.
Am I doing something wrong or just misunderstanding what the forceSet parameter is supposed to do?

Comment: Look like someone else asked a similar question a few days ago and got an answer that could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/42381763/1747875