# LUIS: Action Parameter cannot be passed (with Dialog Execution)

Tags: dialog, parameter-passing, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

By using [LUIS](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/language-understanding-intelligent-service-luis) and it's ["Dialog Execution" under Action Binding](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/LUIS-api/documentation/GetStartedWithLUIS-Advanced#dialog-execution), i'm expecting to be able to provide the **required parameter** (of an Action). (So that the Action can be triggered, or the Dialog can be continued.)

As far as i understand, once the **Parameter** has been asked to provide,  we should provide it in the follow-up query call. For example:

First query:

> `https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/...?subscription-key=...&q=what are the available items`

Then, it asks me "**Under what category?**" (expecting me to provide the required parameter), like:

[image]

Then i provided it in the follow-up query:

> `https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/...?subscription-key=...&q=electronics&contextId=d754ce3...`

But then, seems like i still don't get the value accepted, and therefore it is still showing as `null`. Like this:

[image]

So the **Parameter is not captured**. So that Action can ever be triggered, yet. (Or i cannot reach to next Parameter, if there any)

Am i doing something wrong with it, or what seems to be the problem please?

(Below is the screenshot of that Intent with the "Action Parameters")

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this before. (In fact it still happens). Even in the [Microsoft's Official LUIS API Example DEMOS](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/language-understanding-intelligent-service-luis), **it still happens**.

---

For example, in their ***Weather Bot*** there, just try something like:

**You**: What will the weather be tomorrow?
**Bot**: Where would you like the weather?
**You**: Singapore
**Bot**:

```
{
  "name": "location",
  "required": true,
  "value": null
}
```

---

Then now try again, like:

**You**: What will the weather be tomorrow?
**Bot**: Where would you like the weather?
**You**: in Singapore
**Bot**:

```
{
  "name": "location",
  "required": true,
  "value": [
    {
      "entity": "singapore",
      "type": "builtin.geography.country"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### Conclusion?

**Prepositions**! (in, at, on, by, under, ...) LUIS still doesn't understand the Entity input without the proper preposition provided, sometimes, in some cases.

I'm pretty sure this is the reason for your case. Try again with a preposition.

( This problem took me like 1~2 weeks to realise. Hope Microsoft can improve LUIS better in all this aspects asap. )

Comment: This is correct! I tried again like: `in electronics`. And then it understands the entity now. THANK YOU! This is something like a bug to me. Hope Microsoft can solve this.